FTP alternative for production
I'm currently managing two physical servers, both running Red Hat Linux 8. The primary server is configured with the OS on bare metal, whereas the secondary server utilizes Hyper-V for virtualization. Both servers are dedicated to a single service, FTP, which has recently been experiencing issues.
Given that these servers are in a live production environment, I am exploring alternatives to FTP that could offer improved reliability and performance. Could you please suggest any viable replacements for FTP, considering the current setup of my servers? Your advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

What's the purpose of these servers? I mean, just share files no matter how? Do you need access control on the shared files? What's the capability of the clients, and how are they supposed to access the files (command line, GUI)?

Which were the issues with FTP? Like active mode not allowed due to firewall, security (consider FTPS, not to be confused with SFTP)? SFTP may be an alternative, depending on your needs.

The purpose of the server is to collect video files from various users and upload it through the FTP.the capabilities of the client is they now have root access.
